# Overwrite values.yaml in flux helm deplyoment from other source than the helmchart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I want to deploy a helm chart via flux. The helm chart is inside a repository like for example artifacthub.io where I cannot change it.

The release.yaml looks something like that

```
---
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: cp-helmrelease
  namespace: wordpress
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: wordpress
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: artifacthub
        namespace: bitnami
      version: 15.0.18
  serviceAccountName: m2m-sa
  interval: 10m
  install:
    remediation:
      retries: 3
```

Now I want to overwrite the values.yaml. Using helm, I can easily say helm install xyz and then define the path to the values file. From what I see, I cannot define a path in flux to a file which is not inside the helm chart.
Is there a chance to use a helm chart from artifacthub and store the values.yaml inside my personal git repository and deploy this together with flux?

Answer (score 0):

The official guide has an example of this, but `values` are inline in the `HelmRelease` rather than being in a separate file (but *would* obviously be in your Git repo):

```yaml
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: podinfo
  namespace: default
spec:
  interval: 5m
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: <name|path>
      version: '4.0.x'
      sourceRef:
        kind: <HelmRepository|GitRepository|Bucket>
        name: podinfo
        namespace: flux-system
      interval: 1m
  values:
    replicaCount: 2
```

See: https://fluxcd.io/flux/guides/helmreleases/